# Symfony 'exists' validator

Tags: symfony1

Is there a validator in symfony which checks if a given thing exists in the db?

I need it for forgetten password, so it has to be valid when the email address exists

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isnt one by default but it should be easy to build. Take a look at `SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/validator/sfValidatorDoctrineUnique.class.php` for an example of interacting with the db in a vlaidator (assuming youre using Doctrine). You might also want to look at how sfDoctrineGuardPlugin implements this... I dont recall if its in a validator or as a separate part of the action but i would look to this as a best practice on this type of functionality within symfony since its the "standard" way to implement user authentication and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is already included in symfony.

You may choose based on your ORM

- sfValidatorDoctrineUnique
- sfValidatorPropelUnique

Both are well documented on symfony's homepage.